# How to combine the received data in a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

When I execute an API request, I get a lot of objects that are not connected by a common array. I'm trying to combine them into one state, but only one value is stored. How can I store all the received objects in the general array of my state? Everything would be fine, but I need the array to be stored in the state, in which all objects from the API will lie, in order to transfer this array to Redax

```
 const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 (async () => {
  const users = await axios(world);
  const worldData = users.data;
  setPlanets(worldData);
 })();
 }, [nextTeam, world]);
```

and i take get data

[image]

I am trying to transfer all these objects to state planets, but objects are transferred there individually. Not creating an array.

This is a screenshot of console.log(planets)

[image]

Comment: I do not understand; why are you initializing the state to an empty array, if you do not want the planets to be stored into an array? Anyway, if you want to convert your array into a single object (e.g. `{ naboo: { ... }, tatooine: { ... }, ... }`) you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: What do you exactly get when you console.log(users.data)?

Comment: When i use console.log(users.data), i get many object. First screenshot

Comment: Furthermore, why are you creating a local state, if you want to manage the state with redux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys

```js
let planets = {
  tatooine:{
    population: "1,3M", type: "desert"
  },
  coruscant:{
    population: "130B", type: "city"
  },
}
let array = []
Object.keys(planets).forEach(planet => array.push({
    name: planet,
    ...planets[planet]
}))
console.log(array)
```